# What is this (possible) small jet trainer?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Photographed just now (10/18/2023) near Ellington Field, Texas.

Hunting around on some aircraft pages didn't turn up a match.

I bumped the contrast up to see features better.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like a BAE Systems Hawk...  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BAE_Systems_Hawk

Comment: Indeed! Thanks. New yard bird.

Comment: That appears to be correct based on [FlightRadar24](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZJhG.png) history.

Answer (score 5):

This is a [BAE Systems Hawk Mk 67](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BAE_Systems_Hawk), one of twenty formerly operated by the [South Korean Air Force](https://www.airliners.net/photo/South-Korea-Air-Force/British-Aerospace-T-59-Hawk-67/2016036). It still retains the South Korean camouflage scheme. However, Korea retired its Hawks in 2013, and this Hawk is now privately owned by [RAVN Aerospace](https://www.ravnaero.com/aircraft), based in Houston, Texas.

RAVN have painted their company logo (which I'm guessing is a raven that thinks it's a bird of prey) on the tail, which you can just about make out in your picture.

[image: RAVN BAe Hawk 67][source](https://www.scramble.nl/military-news/air-usa-becomes-ravn-aerospace)

They appear to own at least four of these ex-Korean aircraft.

Comment: Wishing there were an extra +1 available for the description "a raven that thinks it's a bird of prey" - very nice!